# Finding total curvature of $y=x^2,\,x\in[0,1]$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

First I tried $$\begin{align}&r_0(s):=(s,s^2)\\&\implies r_0'(s)=(1,2s)\\
&\implies ||r_0'(s)||=\sqrt{1+4s^2}&\\
&\implies r'(s):=r'_0/||r'_0||=(1/\sqrt{1+4s^2},2s/\sqrt{1+4s^2})\\
&\implies r''(s)=(-8s/(1+4s^2),2/(1+4s^2)^{3/2})\\
&\implies \kappa(s)=||r''||=2\sqrt{64s^4+16s^2+1}/(1+4s^2)^{3/2}\end{align}$$
and it gets messy. I thought I kind of re-parametrized the curve in terms of arc length, it seems didn't work out. Could you tell me where I got wrong?

And I used the formula $$\kappa=\frac{|y''|}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{2}{(1+4s^2)^{3/2}}$$
got the total curvature $$\int_0^1\kappa(s)ds=\int_0^1 2(1+4s^2)^{-3/2}ds\\=\int_0^{\arctan2}\cos\theta \,d\theta=\sin(\arctan2)$$
using the change of variable $2s=\tan\theta$ to make $1+4s^2=1+\tan\theta=\sec^2\theta$. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression for $\kappa(s)$ is not correct. The equation $\kappa(s)=\|r''(s)\|$ doesn't hold since $r(s)$ here is not an arc length parametrization.

The calculation of the integral seems correct, but you misinterpret the formula. The $s$ in the integral for the total curvature stands for an arc length parameter. And, as was mentioned before, $r(s)=(s,s^2)$ is clearly not arc parametrized.

Let's use $t$ as a parameter, to emphasize that the parametrization does not have unit speed, and write $r(t)=(t,t^2)$. Then we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
 \int_{s(0)}^{s(1)} \kappa(s)\,ds &= \int_{0}^{1} \kappa(s(t)) s'(t)\,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{2}{(1+4t^2)^{3/2}} \sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{2}{1+4t^2} \,dt = \arctan 2.
\end{align*}
$$

I also want to learn you a trick that can help you check your answer. The curvature is given by
$$\kappa(s) =\theta'(s)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle that the tangent at the point $r(s)$ makes with the positive horizontal axis. Using this, one can show that
the total curvature is given by
$$
   \theta(s_{\mathrm{end}}) - \theta(s_{\mathrm{begin}}).
$$
For this curve it is very easy to see that $\theta(s_{\mathrm{begin}}) = 0$ and $ \theta(s_{\mathrm{end}}) = \arctan 2$. This follows from the fact that for the graph of a function, the angle $\theta$ satisfies $\tan \theta(x) = y'(x)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Could you explain why $s'(t)=\sqrt{1+4s^2}$? I guess this value is the same as $||r'(t)||$, how $s$ and $r$ are related? And can we write $s$ explicitly in terms of $t$?

Comment: The $s'(t)$ is indeed the same as $\|r'(t)\|$. If you have a parametrization $r(t)$ (not unit speed), then
$$ s(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|r'(t)\|\,dt $$
is the length of the curve $r$ from $t_0$ to $t_1$.

Answer (score 1):

$k(s)=\frac{|r''(s)|}{\sqrt{1+4s^2}}$ where $r'(s)=\frac{(1,2s)}{\sqrt{1+4s^2}}$.

$r''(s)=\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4s^2}},\frac{2s}{\sqrt{1+4s^2}}\Big)'=\Big(\frac{-4s}{(1+4s^2)^\frac{3}{2}},\frac{2}{(1+4s^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \Big)=2(1+4s^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(-2s,1)$ - you miscalculated $r''(s).$

And so $k(s)=2(1+4s^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$.